# String replacement not working when input string made with snprintf

Tags: c, string, replace

I am attempting to substitute parts of a string with keywords in C however when trying to make the string and passing it to the replace_str function it is not producing an output with any replacements whilst making it a static string allows the code to function.

```c
//C default libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep) //from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/replace-a-substring-with-another-string-in-c-170076/
{
    static char buffer[4096];
    char *p;

    if (!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  // Is 'orig' even in 'str'?
        return str;

    strncpy(buffer, str, p - str); // Copy characters from 'str' start to 'orig' st$
    buffer[p - str] = '\0';

    sprintf(buffer + (p - str), "%s%s", rep, p + strlen(orig));

    return buffer;
}

char* expanded(char *line) 
{
    char *keywords[] = { "online","blog" };
    char *retval = "";
        //char *buf = "[1]";
    char buf[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(keywords) / sizeof(keywords[0]); i++) 
    {
        snprintf(buf, 12, "[%d]", i);
        retval = replace_str(line, buf, keywords[i]);
    }

    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    char str[100];

    gets(str);

    printf(expanded(str));

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

When entering 'America[0]' I would expect 'Americaonline' to be returned however I only get America[0] back.

Comment: The second time through the loop, `replace_str` won't find `[1]`, so it just returns the original string. You might want to put a `printf("%s\n", retval);` after the call to `replace_str` to see what's happening.

Comment: @user3386109 Ahh that's exactly the problem, I assume I should add retval = line outside the loop and make it replace_str(retval, buf, keywords[i]). Thanks a lot.